# oh-my-zsh plugin autosuggest use tab to accept suggestions

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I have recently installed two plugins in my oh-my-zsh setup, `zsh-autosuggestions` and `zsh-autocomplete`.
Whenever I type a command I can see, the autocomplete suggestions and some suggestions below the command see the screenshot below, [image]

I would like to use "tab" key to complete the command to `cd kube-patch`, but when I press the tab key, it accepts one of the suggestions from below (like in this case, it will accept "Application")

Is there a way to achieve this?

I have tried this similar question, but none of the options seem to be working.

My guess is may be I am representing tab incorrectly in `.zshrc` file. I have tried following combination

```
bindkey '    ' autosuggest-accept #where the space represent a tab key press

# 2nd one I tried
bindkey '\t' autosuggest-accept #this also didn't work
```

Comment: Why would you do that? Tab is already used within the zsh shell to find tools, would be foolish to overwrite/overrule this. Just use `left` key to accept all or `ctrl+left` for accepting word by word ;)